# changing HttpServletRequest with default class

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

i want to write without request.getParameter(), and it is confusing me. i tried to call class in servlet that already has values to insert in database without getting attributes from database. Could you help me, what type of error is there? (here is my full code with servlet and web.xml)

1. Servletik.class

   ```
    public class Servletik extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public Servletik() {
    super();}

    protected void doPost(UserDao request, HttpServletResponse 
       response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       String fname = null;
       String lname = null;
       String dob = null;
       String email = null;
       String uid = null;
       UserDao.addUser(fname, lname, dob, email, uid);

    }}
   ```
2. DBConnect.java

   ```
       public class DBconnect {
       private static Connection connection = null;

       public static Connection getConnection() {


       try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UserDB", "root","" );

       } 
       catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return connection;}}
   ```
3. UserDAO

   ```
       public class UserDao {

       private static Connection connection;

       public UserDao() {
       connection = (Connection) DBconnect.getConnection();}

       public static void addUser(String fname, String lname, String dob, String email, String uid) {
       try {
       PreparedStatement preparedStatement = ((java.sql.Connection) connection).prepareStatement("insert into users(firstname,lastname,dob,email) values (?, ?, ?, ? );");

       preparedStatement.setString(1, fname);
       preparedStatement.setString(2, lname);
       preparedStatement.setString(3, dob);
       preparedStatement.setString(4, email);
       preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

       } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();}}}
   ```
4. web.xml

   ```
        <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
         <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Servletik</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Servletik</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>nurzhan.servlet.Servletik</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servletik</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Servletik</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        </web-app>
   ```

Comment: are you able to call servlet?

Comment: @swarooppallapothu no, not able to call

Comment: Check by add sout in servlet -> dopost method.

Comment: @swarooppallapothu sorry. can you say more datailed about it?

Comment: I want you to check your servlet is calling are not. For that put sout on servlet doPost method

Comment: @i tried. it doesn't work

Comment: send you web.xml

Comment: @swarooppallapothu done! it's above